# Preventing Tomcat / Jboss from listing files in a directories

Tags: tomcat, jboss

I would like to prevent Tomcat from listing the files in a directory when the URL ends at directory.   This would be like .htaccess for apache.

So that when a user navigates to :
   www.test.com/f_apps/   -- nothing is lised or error message
but going to:
   www.test.com/f_apps/welcome.jsp -- works correctly

I assume it's a change to META-INF/context.xml but I'm still new to Tomcat stuff so wasn't sure how to modify it for this change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to disable the `DefaultServlet`'s `listings` setting in `/conf/web.xml`.

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>listings</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
```

You can find details in its documentation: http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/default-servlet.html

Answer (score 0):

See http://linux-sxs.org/internet_serving/c581.html, you can update the web.xml to do this:

```
This is the first section in web.xml. The options that concern us are :

<init-param>
    <param-name>listings</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
 </init-param>

 Change <param-value> to false and you turn off directory listing. It is that simple.
```